# How to pick file which is placed in S3 bucket only of Saturday ,Sunday and monday in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given is the query which I used to pick the file of the previous day using current timestamp.so on Monday ,i have to manually change the (CURRENT _TIMESTAMP-1) to (CURRENT _TIMESTAMP-2) so that it will pick Sunday's file

```
Select 'abc_' + format(cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 1 as datetime), 'yyyyMMdd') + '*.csv'
```

Is there any to automate the query so that on Monday it will pick automatically Saturday and Sunday file without any manual intervention.

Comment: try something like CURRENT _TIMESTAMP - case when datename(weekday,CURRENT _TIMESTAMP) = 'Monday' then 2 else 1 end

Comment: As a recommendation to make your process even more robust, could you instead process any files that are in the correct location in order? That way if (for whatever reason) the process doesn't run for a couple of days, you don't have to do anything by hand. If you implement that, you get your "Monday needs to process Saturday and Sunday" for free.

Comment: There are tons of files in the location and files can be ordered so have to automate the process the process to pick the file of sat,sun and then Monday on day Monday through the process